# Dynamic work around for pivot function in hana

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

I have a table that consists of the below:

> Emp ID | Earning Type | Value

But instead of showing the employee in a # of lines based on the # of earning types they have i want to display all in one line dynamically.

I am aware i can do it with case whens but i don't wanna hard code the earning type, would it be possible to do that dynamically? insert rows as columns in a temp table with a loop based on the count of earning types?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what context you wanna do that in HANA directly? Normally such things are done by the consuming client (e.g. an analytical client like SAP AfO).

Comment: It's just a query on a SAP B1 DB on Hana that will be inserted in crystal reports.